# Gerund, Infinitive or That Clause in this case

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

If someone expect us to run 40km and we want to say it is ridiculous. Which of the following sentences (or all) can be used ?.

> 1. It is ridiculous for you to expect me to run 40km. (it sounds wrong to me)
> 2. It is ridiculous your expecting me to run 40km.
> 3. It is ridiculous that you expect me to run 40km.

my example can be senseless. I just made up to get more understandable answers for me.

Comment: #1 sounds best to this native US English speaker.  You can find [many examples of "for you to expect me to".](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22for+you+to+expect+me+to%22)

Comment: Can you add more detail why you think any of these are wrong?  Although #2 is a little clumsy, all are grammatical.

Comment: actually I dont know why. it may be because there is a little meaning change when you translate the first to my language.

Comment: #1 also sounds best to us BrE speakers.

Comment: They are all fine and just three different ways of saying the same thing. They all exhibit "subject extraposition", where the subordinate clause subject of the basic non-extraposed version has been moved to the end of the sentence and replaced with the dummy pronoun "it". It's a very common kind of information packaging construction.

Answer (score 1):

The first one, I would phrase it replacing "*for*" with "*of*". Apart from that, its a fine sentence.

> 1. It is ridiculous **of** you to expect me to run 40km.

The second one is mostly fine. Note that it would probably work better with the introduction of the word "*that*" after *ridiculous*. Note the small correction, we should use "*you're*" instead of "*your*" in this case, since it is a contraction of "*... ridiculous that you are expecting me ...*":

> 2. It is ridiculous **that you're** expecting me to run 40km.

The third one is perfectly fine.

> 3. It is ridiculous that you expect me to run 40km.